# How to send HTML email using R

Tags: html, r, email

I have searched SO and well as google and cannot seem to find a solution to my problem. I am trying to send a HTML formatted email within R using sendmailR package. The plain text email works just fine, but then  am unable to switch from plain text to HTML.

My code:

```
require(sendmailR)
from <- "alertbot@companyname.com"
message = "<HTML><body><b>Hello</b></body></HTML>"
to = c("me@companyname.com")
subject = "Test Monitor Alert"

sendmail(from, to, subject, msg = msg,control=list(smtpServer="smtp-gw1.wal-mart.com"),headers=list("Content-Type"="text/html; charset=UTF-8; format=flowed"))
```

I do get the email, but its in plain text and the email body contains the message as is instead of the HTML formatted text. Please help.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

This is possible, cf https://stackoverflow.com/a/21930556/448145
Just add:

```
msg <- mime_part(message)
msg[["headers"]][["Content-Type"]] <- "text/html"
sendmail(from, to, subject, msg = msg, ...)
```

Answer (score 6):

**sendmailR** cannot do this because it is hard-coded to send the message part out as text.  If you look at the packages source, line 38 of sendmail.R is the following:

```
writeLines("Content-Type: text/plain; format=flowed\r\n", sock, sep="\r\n")
```

Change that to

```
writeLines("Content-Type: text/html; format=flowed\r\n", sock, sep="\r\n")
```

like you tried to do through the options and it will work.

**Update**: **sendmailR** now allows html emails (see Karl's answer below and https://stackoverflow.com/a/21930556/448145).

Comment: Wow I was not aware that its hard coded. Do you know of another package that might allow this. I am not comfortable with changing the source of the package itself.

Comment: I up-voted this, but it seems that sendmail.R has changed since you wrote it

Answer (score 4):

With the mailR package (https://github.com/rpremraj/mailR), you could send HTML emails with ease as below:

```
send.mail(from = "sender@gmail.com",
          to = c("recipient1@gmail.com", "recipient2@gmail.com"),
          subject = "Subject of the email",
          body = "<html>The apache logo - <img src=\"http://www.apache.org/images/asf_logo_wide.gif\"></html>",
          html = TRUE,
          smtp = list(host.name = "smtp.gmail.com", port = 465, user.name = "gmail_username", passwd = "password", ssl = TRUE),
          attach.files = c("./download.log", "upload.log"),
          authenticate = TRUE,
          send = TRUE)
```

Answer (score 3):

I prefer to use a specialized Mail agent for this type of task than using an R package. You can for example use [Mutt](http://www.mutt.org/). Available for linux and windows.

Here I am using option -e  to send a command:

```
writeLines(message,
           p<-pipe(paste('mutt -e ','"set content_type=text/html"',
                          from,to,' -s ', subject))
close(p)
```

Answer (score 0):

If nothing else, you can post the html to a php page, and have php send the html email. We'll see if anyone else has a better solutions.

Comment: This is more of a comment than an answer.

Comment: yeah pretty close. but if the source hadn't been editable, it would actually be the (a) solution.

Comment: I am not familiar with php and I am using a windows VM. I will keep this in mind but will try the other options first. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Revisiting this conversation, I used the `mime_part_html` command from the `sendmailR` package to implement HTML in my email:

```
mymsg<-mime_part_html(paste0("Dear Genius:<p>Blah blah, and also you're amazing!"))
)
```

And then:

```
sendmail_options(smtpPort="25") # with port 25 do NOT send credentials
sendmail("blah@wowwee.org",to=c("wow@gmail.com"),
  subject=paste("Another email from me!"),
  msg=mymsg,
  control=list(smtpServer="10.q.x.y", verbose = TRUE)         
  )
```