# Email dataframe as table in email body with SendMailR

Tags: r, sendmailr

I am trying to send a dataframe with SendMailR.  I can send it as an attachment with reasonably good formatting.  However I would like to send the dataframe in the body of the email.  I tried capture.output, print, sprintf but am not even able to get the format close.

e.g. I tried the following syntax

```
for (i in 1:nrow(df)){
 MSG = c(MSG,rownames(df)[1],as.character(unlist(df[i,])),'\n')
} 
MSG = sprintf('%-10s',MSG)
sendmail(from,to,subject,msg = list(MSG,attachment1,attachment2 ... ))
```

In other words, I am thinking that it might be necessary to convert my dataframe into a format with /n and sprintf('s-10%') etc and store it in MSG.  Can someone point me in the right direction?

Comment: I would suggest you to create a HTML table, but I believe that you can't send HTML mail with sendmailR.

Comment: Thanks Julien.  Just as an edit, I just need to send the results of a job via email daily.  I am happy to use another mail sender / change data frame to data table/matrix etc as long as i can send the content in the email body.  Happy to consider any alternatives

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Although sending HTML mails with `sendmailR` is not straighforward, but possible based on a mail discussion with the package author last year (thanks again to Olaf Mersmann for his kind help) - with simply overriding the `Content-Type` header. E.g.:

```
msg <- mime_part('<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0
Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"/>
  <title>HTML demo</title>
  <style type="text/css">
  </style>
</head>
<body>
<h1>HTML demo</h1>
</body>
</html>')

## Override content type.
msg[["headers"]][["Content-Type"]] <- "text/html"

from    <- '<foo@example.com>'
to      <- "<bar@example.com>"
subject <- "HTML test"
body    <- list(msg)
sendmail(from, to, subject, body, ...)
```

---

On the other hand, there is no *real* need for HTML to present tables or a `data.frame` in a human-readable format. There is e.g. the `ascii` package or my `pander` pkg that can turn R objects to markdown. Quick demo:

```
> library(pander)
> panderOptions('table.split.table', Inf)
> pander(head(iris, 3))

-------------------------------------------------------------------
 Sepal.Length   Sepal.Width   Petal.Length   Petal.Width   Species 
-------------- ------------- -------------- ------------- ---------
     5.1            3.5           1.4            0.2       setosa  

     4.9             3            1.4            0.2       setosa  

     4.7            3.2           1.3            0.2       setosa  
-------------------------------------------------------------------

> pander(head(iris, 3), style = 'grid')


+----------------+---------------+----------------+---------------+-----------+
|  Sepal.Length  |  Sepal.Width  |  Petal.Length  |  Petal.Width  |  Species  |
+================+===============+================+===============+===========+
|      5.1       |      3.5      |      1.4       |      0.2      |  setosa   |
+----------------+---------------+----------------+---------------+-----------+
|      4.9       |       3       |      1.4       |      0.2      |  setosa   |
+----------------+---------------+----------------+---------------+-----------+
|      4.7       |      3.2      |      1.3       |      0.2      |  setosa   |
+----------------+---------------+----------------+---------------+-----------+
```

If you want to concatenate this to the e-mail body, use `pander.return` instead that returns character vector instead of writing to the console. And there are some other available table `style`s, also some useful `panderOptions` e.g. to set decimal mark, date format etc: http://rapporter.github.io/pander/

Comment: Thank you so much for your help.  I didn't manage to get pandoc.return to work in email (format looked good in Rstudio but not in my email ... lines are misaligned) but html works well.

Comment: @hjw Maybe you could `paste(..., collapse = '\n')` the stuff from `pander.return` before adding to the e-mail, or `collapse = '<br />'` if sending HTML mail.

Comment: the correct name of the function is `pander_return`

Answer (score 10):

library "xtable" will help to attach a data frame as table in email. Try this

```
   library(xtable)

   body=print(xtable(dataframe,caption = "Heading for the table"), type="html", caption.placement = "top")
```

Comment: I was struggling with the same issue. Thought some one with my condition will get some help.

Answer (score 1):

As an alternative to `sendmailR`, here's an example using the `gt` package for converting the table to HTML and the `blastula` package  for sending the email. Both packages are from RStudio: [blastula](https://rstudio.github.io/blastula/) and [gt](https://gt.rstudio.com/index.html).

```
library(blastula)
library(gt)

tbl_html <- 
  mtcars %>% 
  gt() %>%
  as_raw_html()

email <-
  compose_email(
    body = blocks(tbl_html)
    )

email %>%
  smtp_send(
    to = 'recipient@email.com',
    from = 'sender@gmail.com',
    subject = "Test email with table",
    credentials = creds_file("gmail_creds")
  )
```

To set the credentials the first time use (in this case using a gmail address):

```
create_smtp_creds_file(
  file = "gmail_creds",
  user = 'sender@gmail.com',
  provider = "gmail"
)
```

You can also use markdown in the body.