# How to retain date/time format in xtable for an email

Tags: r, email, html-email, xtable

I am looking to email a nicely formatted table from R using xtable. I found [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21929170/email-dataframe-as-table-in-email-body-with-sendmailr) explaining how to email an xtable easily, which works and the table looks great. However each time I do my date/time columns convert to numeric.

My email code:

```
body=print(xtable(myData), type="html")
```

My dates convert from YYYY-MM-DD hh:mm:ss to numeric (e.g. 1508117307.17). I've tried a number of ways to try to convert it back using things like transform and as.Date(), but no matter what I do the dates still convert to numeric.

Is it possible to coerce xtable to retain my original date/time format?

Thank you!

Comment: Have you tried converting the date to character before printing the table?

Comment: @tobiasegli_te I've just done that and it seems to work.

Comment: By jove it worked! If i transform as.character() it works perfectly. I appreciate the help very much!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Convert the date to character using `as.character()` before printing the table should do the job.

Disclaimer: I moved this answer here from the comments so other users can make use of the solution.