# Send HTML message using gmailr

Tags: r, gmail-api, gmailr

I want to be able to use the gmailR package to send R-generated HTML reports via email inline(not as attachments). I'm unable to even send a basic HTML email using `gmailr`. I've attempted the following unsuccessfully and need some help:

```
library(gmailr)
gmail_auth("oauth.token.json", scope = "compose")

test_email <- mime() %>%
 to("you@gmail.com") %>%
 from("me@gmail.com") %>%
 subject("This is a subject") 
test_email$body <- "I wish <b>this</b> was bold"
send_message(test_email)
```

RESULT: Message successfully sends, but body is plain text - not HTML

**Attempt 2**

```
test_email <- mime() %>%
 to("you@gmail.com") %>%
 from("me@gmail.com") %>%
 subject("This is a subject") %>%
 html_body("I wish <b>this</b> was bold")
test_email$body
```

RESULT: test_email$body is NULL

**Attempt 3**

```
test_email <- mime() %>%
 to("you@gmail.com") %>%
 from("me@gmail.com") %>%
  subject("This is a subject") 
test_email$body <- html_body("I wish <b>this</b> was bold")
```

RESULT: Error in mime$parts : $ operator is invalid for atomic vectors

**Attempt 4**

```
test_email <- mime() %>%
 to("you@gmail.com") %>%
 from("me@gmail.com") %>%
 subject("This is a subject") 
test_email$parts <- c(html_body("I wish <b>this</b> was bold"),text_body("plain"))
```

RESULT: Error in mime$parts : $ operator is invalid for atomic vectors

Comment: it appears that this is related to the issue referenced here: https://github.com/jimhester/gmailr/issues/9

Comment: While this does not answer your gmailr related issue, I recommend you to give mailR a shot that easily supports sending HTML formatted emails (https://github.com/rpremraj/mailR).

Comment: Attempts 3 and 4 clearly are invalid. As the documentation states, the first arguments for text_body() and html_body() are a mime object, not a text string. The can be used to set the html or text body on a mime object, like so: text_body(test_email, "Plain text string")

Comment: As for Attempt 2: the fact that test_email$body is NULL is probably normal. HTML email is sent as a multipart mime message, and that data is stored elsewhere in your test_email object. But what was the effect of attempt 2, did it actually send an email? send_message returns a status object, what does it return in your case for Attempt 2?

Comment: I use sendmailR successfully for that purpose, cf https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19844762/how-to-send-html-email-using-r/21993248#21993248

Comment: @JackCase did you get t his to work? The code below actually doesn't work for me. I'm getting blank emails  sent still.

Answer (score 2):

Well - this is what I tried:

```
library(gmailr)
gmail_auth('mysecret.json', scope = 'compose') 

test_email <- mime() %>%
 to("to@gmail.com") %>%
 from("from@gmail.com") %>%
 subject("This is a subject") %>%
 html_body("<html><body>I wish <b>this</b> was bold</body></html>")
send_message(test_email)
```

And voila (German gmail...) [image]

Seems like the trick was simply to put in real HTML - including `<html>` and `<body>` - to make gmail understand.