# how to send html file in the body of the mail using R?

Tags: html, r, email, sendmailr

I have an html file as an result of my Rmarkdown code. Now I need to send an email with this html file directly in the body of the email, and not in the attachement. I was trying the solution from this post: ["send HTML email using R" post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19844762/how-to-send-html-email-using-r)
But it seems that it works only with html text and not html file. 
Here what I've tried to do:

```
library(sendmailR)
from<-"<sender@enterprise.lan>"
to<-c("<reciever@enterprise.com>")
message ="./TEST.html"
subject = "Test HTML"
msg <- mime_part(message)
msg[["headers"]][["Content-Type"]] <- "file/html"
sendmail(from, to, subject, msg = msg,control=list(smtpServer="localhost"),headers=list("Content-Type"="file/html; charset=UTF-8; format=flowed"))
```

This trial send me an email but with "TEST.html" file attached, and not in the body directly.
Obviously I'm doing something wrong, I'm struggling with this task for days, can someone help me, please?

Comment: Answered here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21929170/email-dataframe-as-table-in-email-body-with-sendmailr

Comment: Thank you Benjamin. I've tried to use this solution, as I understand I need to include my html file into html code, here is how I tried to do it:
...<body> <object type="text/html" data="TEST2.html"></object>
</body>... I've also tried this: <link rel="import" href="TEST2.html">
But every time the mail that I receive is empty. data="./TEST2.html" give also an empty mail

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the `mailR` package to easily send emails in HTML format as follows:

```
send.mail(from = "sender@gmail.com",
          to = c("recipient1@gmail.com", "recipient2@gmail.com"),
          subject = "Subject of the email",
          body = "<html>The apache logo - <img src=\"http://www.apache.org/images/asf_logo_wide.gif\"></html>", # can also point to local file (see next example)
          html = TRUE,
          smtp = list(host.name = "smtp.gmail.com", port = 465, user.name = "gmail_username", passwd = "password", ssl = TRUE),
          authenticate = TRUE,
          send = TRUE)
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, the problem is that i'm working out of Rstudio, and I can't install the library mailR. I receive this message: Warning message:
package ‘mailR’ is not available (for R version 3.2.2)

Answer (score 0):

I used the `mime_part_html` command from the `sendmailR` package to implement HTML in my email:

```
mymsg<-mime_part_html(paste0("Dear Nerd:<p>Blah blah blah, and also you're amazing!"))
)
```

And then:

```
sendmail_options(smtpPort="25") # with port 25 do NOT send credentials
sendmail("blah@wowwee.org",to=c("blah@gmail.com"),
  subject=paste("Another email from me!"),
  msg=mymsg,
  control=list(smtpServer="10.q.x.y", verbose = TRUE)         
  )
```