# Rmarkdown html file as body of eamil using sendmailR package

Tags: html, r, email, r-markdown, sendmailr

I've created an html file using Rmarkdown. It is stored in my home directory. I'd like to use this file to create the **body** of an html email which I'll send with sendmailR package (sendmail() function).

The problem is, I can't get the html to display inline; it only shows as an attachment.

Note: I'm running this from a company server which seems to not work with other email packages in R. I'm open to alternatives using other packages, but I can't seem to get it to play nice with smtp authentication.

Here's the code that's generating an attachment:

```
msg2 = list(mime_part(x = 
                         "/home/markdown_test/markdown_test.html", 
                      name = "markdown_test.html"))


## Override content type.
#msg2[["headers"]][["Content-Type"]] = "text/html"
msg2[['headers']]$`Content-Disposition`= "inline"

sendmail(from = "test@gmail.com",
         to = c("test@gmail.com"),
         subject = "TEst Subject",
         msg = msg2,
         html = TRUE,
         smtp = list(
            host.name = "aspmx.l.google.com",
            port = 25,
            user.name = "abc@gmail.com",
            passwd = "pwd",
            ssl = TRUE
         ),

         authenticate = TRUE,
         send = TRUE)
```

I've tried various combinations of updating the headers line; in some cases no email hits the inbox at all. in other cases an email comes through, but with an empty body an an attachment titled "markdown_test.html." Note that this attachment can be opened and does have the content I'd like in the body of the email.

Comment: Does this help?  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19844762/how-to-send-html-email-using-r